# How do I setup the packages that are not in PYPI in requirements.txt for developing on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, web-deployment

I download a package from https://bitbucket.org/spirit/guess_language/downloads/guess_language-spirit-0.5a4.tar.bz2

now I'm going to deploy my app on Heroku and it tells me:

*"Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement guess-language-spirit==0.5a4 (from app==1.0->-r /tmp/build_a92af1ad389e47ddc669f4154c077224/requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: 0.5a5, 0.5, 0.5.1, 0.5.2, 0.5.3)"*

so how do I put this package into requirements.txt?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
https://bitbucket.org/spirit/guess_language/downloads/guess_language-spirit-0.5a4.tar.bz2#egg=guess-language-spirit-0.5a4
```

Usually that egg annotation is used for VCS systems rather than a tar file, but try anyway. See details about that in:

- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support

Comment: directly add this in my requirements.txt? I tried, but didn't work.

Comment: Reading the message again, it may actually be because it explicitly says it doesn't want 0.5a4. You need to use one of 0.5a5, 0.5, 0.5.1, 0.5.2, 0.5.3 because something is qualifying what version it wants.

Comment: I directly add https://bitbucket.org/spirit/guess_language/downloads/guess_language-spirit-0.5a4.tar.bz2 at the bottom of requirements.txt, and it is successfully pushed.     I remember I did this before and didn't work. so weired.

Comment: I have seen issues before with ordering in ``requirements.txt``. If you have a ``tar.gz`` URL, and that package is required by some other package, but that other package doesn't actually have an ``install_requires`` in the package specification, there is no guarantee that ``pip`` will install the ``tar.gz`` package first. Thus when it attempts to install the other package which needs it, that will fail.